# Do images need to be numbered for Keras CNN training/testing?

Tags: keras

I've noticed that for any tutorial or example of a Keras CNN that I've seen, the input images are numbered, e.g.:

- dog0001.jpg
- dog0002.jpg
- dog0003.jpg
- ...

Is this necessary?

I'm working with an image dataset with fairly random filenames (the classes come from the directory name), e.g.:

- picture_A2.jpg
- image41110.jpg
- cellofinterest9A.jpg

I actually want to keep the filenames because they mean something to me, but do I need to append sequential numbers to my image files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No they can be of different names, it really depends on how you load your data. In your case, you can use `flow_from_directory` to generate the training data and indeed the directory will be the associated class, this is part of [ImageDataGenerator](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/#imagedatagenerator-methods).